# ServiceHostFactory missing in .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, c#-4.0

This is driving me nuts, maybe I'm missing something but I'm trying to upgrade a .NET 3.5 application to .NET 4.0 and the only problem I'm running into is this class:

3.5 Code:

```
   public class ServiceHostFactory : System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) {
            return new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
        }
    }
```

When I upgrade to 4.0, it appears that "ServiceHostFactory" doesn't exist (it is red). Going into Object Browser, under System.ServiceModel.Activation, it indeed shows no ServiceHostFactory.

According to this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactory.aspx

It should be supported in 4.0. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The System.ServiceModel.dll has some items in the System.ServiceModel.Activation namespace.

However, ServiceHostFactory is in the System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll itself.  So you need to add a reference to that assembly.  Keep in mind that by default, VS2010 appears to want to use the .NET 4 Client Profile, so you'll need to change that to the regular .NET 4 profile before you can add the reference to System.ServiceModel.Activation.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Found the .NET 4 Client Profile thing early on, that was another half hour wasted ;)